# BURP Suite Testing

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I am developing a mobile application. I want to test this mobile application using BURP suite. I am new to testing using BURP Suite. I dont know how to do it. Please let me know if there is any webpage or forum for guidelines for using this BURP suite?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked [here](http://www.securityninja.co.uk/hacking/burp-suite-tutorial-the-intruder-tool/)? Maybe it could help a little.

**EDIT**

You want to take a look at [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid) in order to create the proxy FROM your device. [Tutorial](http://madteam.co/news/2011/11/tutorial-app-review-proxy-droid/) here;)

Comment: Thanks michal.How do you add your application to the BURP suite?

Comment: I went to scope and added location (url) of my application but it does  not show anything in the site map.

Comment: Look at this step-by-step 
http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/burp-suite-walkthrough/
I believe simple telling where to click or so wouldn't help the purpose, you need to get the real grasp of it by understanding the workflow!:)

Comment: And this will help too! 
http://forum.portswigger.net/index.cgi?board=how&action=display&thread=10

Comment: Where EXACTLY is your app located? Device, server, localhost?

Comment: My application is located in an android device. its an android application.

Comment: In my android mobile, I have enabled the wi-fi proxy, set the proxy host and port. But, when I run my application, BURP suite does not show anything.

Comment: My application is a hybrid android app and running my app in a phonegap. Still, Do I need to have root access for running my app?

Comment: I have downloaded superuser for root access. How do I add my application to the superuser. How could I change the host and port for my application using superuser?